# Behaviour of meshing in BoundaryDiscretizeRegion

Tags: mesh

I have come across some strange behaviour in the function `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]`, using Mathematica 11.0.0 on Mac OSX 10.11.6.

It seems like the option `MaxCellMeasure` no longer changes the quality of the mesh.

Using the example from the Wolfram documentation ([here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html)), under scope/quality

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {1, 0.1, 
  0.01}
```

I get the following as output:

[image: Example of meshing bug]

clearly no change in the mesh quality.

Is this a known bug or should it be reported?

Strangely this doesn't seem to be a problem for Implicit Regions at least in 3D e.g.

```
dodeq = z^6 - 5 (x^2 + y^2) z^4 + 5 (x^2 + y^2)^2 z^2 - 
   2 (x^4 - 10 x^2 y^2 + 5 y^4) x z + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3 - (x^2 + 
      y^2 + z^2)^2 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - 1;
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[dodeq <= 0, {x, y, z}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {1, 0.1, 0.01}
```

which gives:

[image: example of implicit region]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change that to, "no *apparent* change in the mesh quality".

```
meshes = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {1, 0.1, 0.01};
Length@*MeshCoordinates /@ meshes
ListPlot@*MeshCoordinates /@ meshes
(* {42, 63, 629} *)
```

[image]

Now it's more clear you are getting a better mesh, you just can't see the change visibly.  It's like comparing a 42-sided regular polygon to a 630-sided regular polygon, they both look like circles.  In 3D the changes are just more visible.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Is there however a maximum size that is now implemented that wasn't implemented before? For example when I do `meshes = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[], 
     MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {5, 2, 1};
Length@*MeshCoordinates /@ meshes
ListPlot@*MeshCoordinates /@ meshes` I get the same number of mesh points. Is some other parameter controlling this like AccuracyGoal ?

Comment: It seems that there is a shape-dependent minimum number of points coded in to define a mesh region.  Which makes sense, you wouldn't make a mesh region from a circle and use 4 points.  For a `Disk` or `Ellipsoid` in 2D, I can't get less than 42 points.  For a `Rectangle` though, I can get as low as 4 points, and any general polygon can't have fewer mesh points than points that make up the polygon.  This makes it seem to me that when the system renders a `Disk`, it renders like `RegularPolygon[42]`

Comment: @JasonB It's not shape dependent but `AccuracyGoal` dependent: `meshes = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> #, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 1] & /@ {1, 0.1, 0.01};`

Comment: @user21 - That makes sense, since with a `Rectangle` you can reduce the number of points to 4 without changing the accuracy. There still seems to be a minimum for `Disk` and `Ellipsoid` primitives - I can't find a combination of `AccuracyGoal` and `MeshCoordinates` that will turn a `Disk[]` into a triangle (it can be an octagon though)

Comment: for reference in v10.1 the coordinate counts for the 3 cases are `{9, 89, 889}` i.e. much coarser for the `1` case.  Of course you cant call this a bug since the criterea is a "maximum".